# Mac Address Input Box

Tags: mask, mac-address, inputbox

I'm creating an input box that will only allow 17 characters and is formatted to display as a mac address.

I've added the first 11 characters, the rest the ( last 4 digits of mac) will be added by the user. Is there any way to stop them deleting the initial characters I've preset ?

```
<script>
function macAdd(val){
if (/[^\w-]|_/.test(val))
{alert("invalid form only alpanumeric and -")
return val}


val=val.replace(/[^\w-]|_/g,'')
val=val.replace(/(\w{2})([^-])/g,'$1'+'-'+'$2')
val=val.replace(/-$/,'')
return val
}
</script>

<input type="text" onkeypress="this.value=macAdd(this.value)" size="30" value="00-00-00-00" maxlength="17"> </p>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to achieve what I'm looking to do.

```
<form>
<input type="text" style="width:130px;" value="00-00-00-00-" readonly><input type="text" style="margin-left : -50px;width:50px;" maxlength="5" onkeypress="this.value=macAdd(this.value)">
</form>
```